# LLRB Tree How to prove if left and left of left node are black, then this node must be a red node?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

Im learning the delete operation on [Left-leaning Red Black Tree](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/08Dagstuhl/RedBlack.pdf) invented by Prof. Sedgewick. In delete operation, a node could be only deleted from a 3-node or a 4-node but 2-node. In order to ensure we dont end up at 2-node, we push the red link down when both the left and left of left of this node are black (if the cmp < 0) by the code below

```
// Assuming that h is red and both h.left and h.left.left
// are black, make h.left or one of its children red.
private Node moveRedLeft(Node h) {
    assert (h != null);
    assert isRed(h) && !isRed(h.left) && !isRed(h.left.left);

    flipColors(h);
    if (isRed(h.right.left)) { 
        h.right = rotateRight(h.right);
        h = rotateLeft(h);
    }
    return h;
}
```

The fact is before we invoke this function, there is not any check if this node is red. So, This must be one of the characters of LLRB. Actually the image below just show this.

[image: one possible llrb tree]

But how to prove this?

Comment: What have you done to try to answer your own question?  We expect you to make some effort and do some research on your own before asking, and to show us in the question what you've done.  Have you tried to prove it?  If so, where did you get stuck?  Have you tried writing out a bunch of small examples to see what patterns you can spot?

Comment: @D.W. Yes, I spend two days on it, now I can implement full feature LLRB without seeing the reference. But Im not sure I understand it in the right way. So, basically I just go through the coding stage, then I will try to understand it by study the characters of this tree. Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to answer my own question.